# Find & replace multiple numbers at the same time

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with a bunch of numbers and I need to increment some of them by one.

Except that if replace all the 2 by 3, then when I try and replace all the 3 by 4, everything will become 4.

I want to know if theres something I could do to prevent that

Comment: replace all 0 with letter X
work down from 9 to 1
replace all X to 1

Comment: Start from the top number. Increment 4 to 5. Then 3 to 4. Then 2 to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start replacing from top order and you will get an result:)

Replace 3 with 4 first and then 2 with 3.

Thanks

Comment: well I feel dumb now, how did I not think about doing it like that?!? thanks!

Comment: hey it happens some time when we think more then expect, and this type of mistakes happen :P

Answer (score 0):

Easy way Come by reverse order.That is if largest number is 10 , replace to 11 now all 10 become 11 next replace all 9 to 10.. so on.